# Running multiple map tasks in parallel

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using hadoop 2.0. When I alter the number of map tasks using **job.setNumMapTasks**, the number is as expected (in the number of sequence files in the output folder and the number of containers), but they do not run in parallel, but only 2 at a time. For instance, when I set the number of map tasks to 5, its like 2 of them executed first, followed by 2 more, followed by 1. I have an 8-core system and would like to utilize it to the fullest. A bit of online hunting (including StackOverflow) seemed to suggest a few things and I tried the following:

1. Adjusted the parameter "mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum" in mapred-site.xml to set the number of tasks running in parallel. I set it to 8.
2. Reduced the parameter, "mapred.max.split.size". My input sequence file size is 8448509 or approximately 8 MB. Hence I set it to 2097152 (2 MB).
3. Lowered the DFS block size, "dfs.block.size in dfs-site.xml. I learnt that the block size by default is 64MB. I lowered it to 2097152 (2 MB).

In spite of all this, I do not see any change in performance. Its still 2 map tasks at a time. I did not format my hdfs and reload the sequence file after 3. Not sure if that is the reason though.

You can access my configuration files at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jnxsm5m2ic1evn4/zPVcdk8GTp. Am I missing something here?

Also, I had another question. Some posts seem to mention that job.setNumMapTasks is just an indicator to the environment and the actual number is decided by the environment. However, I always find the number of tasks as whatever I specify. Is that expected?

Thanks and Regards,
Samudra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic mapreduce framework(MR1) you can set the number of map slots by using the property`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`. But in YARN, things are different. See the below discussion on map/reduce slots in YARN

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/J564g9A8tPE

Comment: This answer points to a members only discussion which cannot be seen by the general public.